# Searching a list of similar elements for a given value

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have some XML like this:

```
<Team ...some attributes...>
  <Name>My Team</Name>
  <Player uID="player1">
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
    <Stat Type="first_name">Name</Stat>
    <Stat Type="last_name">Last</Stat>
    <Stat Type="birth_date">bday</Stat>
    <Stat Type="birth_place">bplace</Stat>
    <Stat Type="weight">84</Stat>
    <Stat Type="height">183</Stat>
    <Stat Type="jersey_num">1</Stat>
  </Player>
  <Player uID="player2">
    ...
  </Player>
  ...
</Team>
```

I want to search for players by `jersey_num`.  I'm using Nokogiri and this code gets me sort of close:

```
feed.xpath("/Team[@uID='#{team_uid}']//Player/Stat[@Type='jersey_num']")
```

That returns all the players in a given team, and an array of their jersey number attribute rows, but I want to find a player with a given jersey number, and then pull its `uID`.

I can do that with ancestor, but first I need this search to yield only one matching player.  I realize at the moment I'm not searching for it, but I'm not sure how to search given the `Stat Type` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "... but I want to find a player with a given jersey number, and then pull its uID"

Then the xpath parameter should look about like this :

```
/Team[@uID='#{team_uid}']//Player[Stat[@Type='jersey_num' and .='#{jersey_num}']]/@uID
```

or maybe without trailing `/@uID` to get `Player` element, and then do further extraction from ruby code. Notice that `Stat[....]` part in the above xpath filters `Stat` element by `Type` attribute value and by value of the element itself.

Comment: that works beautifully, i knew it could be done with xpath alone.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I expect there is a better way to go about it:

```
jersey_number = '23'
players = feed.xpath("/Team[@uID='#{team_uid}']//Player")
player = players.xpath("//Stat[@Type='jersey_num']").detect do |jersery|
  jersery.text == jersey_number
end
player
#=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x95e8f4 name="Stat" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x9407dc name="Type" value="jersey_num">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x940048 "23">]>
```

Comment: Is this your answer, or the code that should have been included in the question?

Comment: Don't do things like `jersery.text == jersey_number`. The `text` can contain whitespace, such as spaces, tabs, new-lines, carriage-returns, non-breaking-spaces, i.e., things that are NOT what you want to compare to. Instead, clean up your text before comparing.

Comment: @theTinMan, this is an answer - it returns what i wanted, but I think it's not great...what you said about jersey.text is maybe one of the reasons why.  thanks for that tip though, i will keep that in mind going forward